# MySQL: database performance_schema does not exist when running from RAM disk

Tags: mysql

I’m running **MySQL Community 5.7.13**, started manually from a ramdisk with the following command:

```
sudo mysqld --port=3307 --socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld-testing.sock" --user mysql --pid-file="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld-testing.pid" --datadir="/tmp/mysqlramdisk" --skip-grant-tables &
```

This worked fine when using MySQL 5.6, but for 5.7, some things seem broken. Most notably, the database `performance_schema` does not exist, leading to stuff like:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist

$ mysql_upgrade -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld-testing.sock -u root
Error occurred: Cannot select database.
```

The folder `/tmp/mysqlramdisk` is emptied before every start, so there is no old databases (from 5.6) lying around.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sw development, this is pure DBA or sysops stuff.

Comment: Some contents of the --datadir directory are put there when you install MySQL. If you start MySQL with an empty data directory, it's a little like a talking burro. It's not amazing it works badly, it's amazing it works at all.

Comment: @OllieJones It used to work with 5.6, as I said. I could fix it in the meantime, will wrap the solution up, unless the question is to be closed as not fitting anyways.

Comment: If putting the entire directory in a ramdisk worked in 5.6, but not in 5.7, you should file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com .